Red Hat 8 - Decoding firewalld rejects
I have started testing the firewall on a Red Hat 8 system.  My only question here is how
to debug the cryptic data that means almost nothing.  How do I trace a rejection back to
the source of the problem of why a request was rejected??
I created the following to write these to a different log location for tracking
Created a new file called /etc/rsyslog.d/firewall-drop.conf and added the following
into the file
:msg,contains,"_DROP" /var/log/firewalld-drop.log
:msg,contains,"_REJECT" /var/log/firewalld-drop.log
& stop

Restart the service to take affect.  I receive information in this log file like:
Sep 13 10:03:07 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:11:11:b0:3a:6e:08:00 SRC=10.2.3.87 DST=10.2.255.255 LEN=229 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=60776 PROTO=UDP SPT=138 DPT=138 LEN=209 
Sep 13 10:03:22 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:70:b5:e8:4b:04:dc:08:00 SRC=10.2.3.203 DST=10.2.255.255 LEN=72 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=63130 PROTO=UDP SPT=57621 DPT=57621 LEN=52 
Sep 13 10:03:25 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:e0:2b:e9:1c:d4:be:08:00 SRC=10.2.3.68 DST=10.2.255.255 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=48193 PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=137 LEN=58 
Sep 13 10:03:26 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:e0:2b:e9:1c:d4:be:08:00 SRC=10.2.3.68 DST=10.2.255.255 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=48194 PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=137 LEN=58 
Sep 13 10:03:26 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:e0:2b:e9:1c:d4:be:08:00 SRC=10.2.3.68 DST=10.2.255.255 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=48195 PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=137 LEN=58 
Sep 13 10:03:38 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:e0:2b:e9:1c:d4:be:08:00 SRC=10.2.3.68 DST=10.2.255.255 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=48196 PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=137 LEN=58 
Sep 13 10:03:38 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:e0:2b:e9:1c:d4:be:08:00 SRC=10.2.3.68 DST=10.2.255.255 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=48197 PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=137 LEN=58 
Sep 13 10:03:39 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:e0:2b:e9:1c:d4:be:08:00 SRC=10.2.3.68 DST=10.2.255.255 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=48198 PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=137 LEN=58 
Sep 13 10:03:48 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e0:55:3d:11:04:f0:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=55985 PROTO=2 
Sep 13 10:03:52 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:70:b5:e8:4b:04:dc:08:00 SRC=10.2.3.203 DST=10.2.255.255 LEN=72 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=63131 PROTO=UDP SPT=57621 DPT=57621 LEN=52

The reality here is that this data means nothing to me and it's certainly not intuitive.  How are
we supposed to figure out what the root cause of a firewall rejection is??  After a few searches,
I've found nothing to indicate how to read this jibberish correctly.  This is my first time
playing with the firewall so I might just be missing something really basic here???

Not all that cryptic if you have a minimal understanding of tcp/ip networking.
Sep 13 10:03:07 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:11:11:b0:3a:6e:08:00 SRC=10.2.3.87 DST=10.2.255.255 LEN=229 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=60776 PROTO=UDP SPT=138 DPT=138 LEN=209 
Sep 13 10:03:39 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:e0:2b:e9:1c:d4:be:08:00 SRC=10.2.3.68 DST=10.2.255.255 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=48198 PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=137 LEN=58 


Ignore the "MAC", SRC is the machine whose packet got dropped; DST the intended recipient (most likely the machine you're logged into), the most relevant parts are PROTO & DPT, protocol and destination port.
grep -P '\W13[78]' /etc/services 
netbios-ns  137/tcp             # NETBIOS Name Service
netbios-ns  137/udp
netbios-dgm 138/tcp             # NETBIOS Datagram Service
netbios-dgm 138/udp

which tells us that a machine is trying to talk windows share and you're dropping it.
Sep 13 10:03:52 localhost kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:70:b5:e8:4b:04:dc:08:00 SRC=10.2.3.203 DST=10.2.255.255 LEN=72 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=63131 PROTO=UDP SPT=57621 DPT=57621 LEN=52

57621 is not a standard port, but a google search for udp port 57621 suggests that it's something trying to talk spotify (which may or may not be the case).

This is very helpful.  I think I can get the information I need now to figure what is being rejected and whether I can ignore it or not.

You're most welcome, one is glad to be of service. :)
